# Equation to calculate percentage of $\color{red}{\text{hot}}$ water needed to raise $\color{blue}{\text{cold}}$ water to $x^\circ$ using mixing valve

Tags: percentages, ratio

I need an equation to calculate the percentage of $\color{red}{\text{hot}}$ water it would need to raise $\color{blue}{\text{cold}}$ water to $x$ degrees using a mixing valve. The mixing valve decreases the amount of $\color{blue}{\text{cold}}$ water as it increases the amount of $\color{red}{\text{hot}}$ water.

- $75\% \color{red}{\text{ hot }} 25\% \color{blue}{\text{ cold}}$
- $80\% \color{red}{\text{ hot }} 20\% \color{blue}{\text{ cold}}$
- etc.

Attached is a drawing for reference. I was able to calculate the mixing valve percent manually. I want a formula that can do it automatically.

[image]

Comment: @RohitSingh It's good to inline the image, but I'm dubious about the utility of adding color to the text (I've left it, though), and definitely do not change the capitalization to something that's actually non-standard English. That last bit I've changed back to the OP's style; in general, do not fix the OP's grammar unless it's actively misleading.

Comment: @BrianTung "I'm dubious about the utiliy of adding color to the text." That's $\color{green}{\text{just}} \color{red}{\text{ your}} \color{blue}{\text{ opinion}}$.

Comment: @terrace: LOL of course. But I'm generally in favor of leaving it the way the OP had it. If the OP had had color I'd have advocated leaving that too.

Comment: @terrace How can your color the text???

Answer (score 1):

Let $T_h$ be the temperature of the hot water, $T_c$ be the temperature of the cold water, $T_m$ the temperature of the mixture, and $r$ the mixing ratio.

Then, we have $$T_m=rT_h+(1-r)T_c.$$

This yields

$$r=\dfrac{T_m-T_c}{T_h-T_c}.$$